# How to use a function to build an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am a little rusty on my PHP and I am trying to create a function that will build an array. Essentially, I am trying to have an associative array of contacts ($contacts), with each individual element being a separate array ($contact). For starters, I would like it to be able to have a UniqueID,FirstName,and LastName within the elements. Here is the direction I am heading in right now:

```
    <?php

$contact=array();
function createContact($Unique_ID,$FirstName,$LastName){
global $contact;
$contact=array("Unique_ID"=>$Unique_ID,"First_Name"=>$FirstName,"Last_Name"=>$LastName);
};
createContact("123456","John","Smith");
createContact("654321","Jane","Doe");
createContact("331143","Steve","Sample");

foreach($contact as $key=>$value){
echo $key.",",$value."<br>";
};

?>
```

This should create the $contact array with 3 separate records, but it only adds the last entry (In this case Steve Sample because it is the last one that was run). I remember learning somewhat about the global variables, but I think I am using it incorrectly. After I solve this, I will find a way to make an array containing all of these arrays.

Comment: You need to *append* to the array: `$contact[] = array(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the array `$contact` every time you invoke `createContact()`.
You have to **append** the new records

```
function createContact($Unique_ID,$FirstName,$LastName){
    $contact[] = array("Unique_ID" => $Unique_ID, "First_Name" => $FirstName, "Last_Name" => $LastName);
};
```

Note the `[]` to indicate that you want to append another entry.

If you want to print these you probably want to do something like this

```
foreach ($contact as $item) {
    echo "ID = " . $item["Unique_ID"] . "<br>";
    echo "First name = " . $item["First_Name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Last name = " . $item["Last_Name"] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need additional array.

```
$final_array = array();
```

and use

```
array_push($final_array, $contact);
```

inside the createContact function

Comment: This works as well, thank you. One more question though. How would I go about echo-ing out this final array in a readable format? Like how could I use a foreach to print out every $contact within the $final_array?

Comment: Lets say, you have the following array after you push the data:

    $final_array = array (
                        array ( 'name' => 'prashant', 'phone' => '12345'),
                        array ( 'name' => 'chris', 'phone' => '1234567'),
                        );

    To print this:

    if(true===is_array($final_array)){    
        foreach($final_array as $contact)
        {
            if(true==is_array($contact))
            {
                echo "Name : ".$contact['name']. ", Phone: ".$contact['phone']."<br />";
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Hello, the only issue with this is that it is printing all of the records every time it tries to print the next one. For example, it will echo out "Name: John, Phone:123456; Name: John, Phone: 123456 Name: Jane, Phone:654321;"